# Keyboard focus in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, keyboard, ipython, spyder

I want to use `tkMessageBox.askyesno` with top level and keyboard focus. 
I wrote the following code.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

root=Tkinter.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',False)
root.lift()

if tkMessageBox.askyesno('Yes or No?','Yes or No?'):
    pass
else:
    pass
root.withdraw()
```

I can create a askyesno message box with top level focus. 
However, I can't focus to keyboard to select a yes or no button.

I usually execute codes on IPython in Spyder. When I execute the above code on the command line, i.e. `!python C:/.../test.py` on IPython console, I can always make the dialog appear with keyboard focus. However, when I  execute the above code on  IPython console, I can NOT always make the dialog appear with keyboard focus. A keyboard focus on an editor in Spyder.

Why are they different results? 
It seems to be a problem in Spyder. Is there any ways to always make the dialog appear with keyboard focus on  IPython console for ease (Running codes on the command line takes time little bit)?
Of course, I can select a button with the mouse and make a keyboard focus on the dialog by Alt-Tabbing. However, I want to select a button by cursor keys and press enter key just after appearing the dialog without any other operations for ease.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You select a button with the mouse, not the keyboard.  To use the keyboard you have to bind the key(s) you want to use  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: The default button is the Yes button. So if you set focus on the dialog -- either by clicking on its title bar or Alt-Tabbing to it -- then press the Return key, it will respond with Yes. To change the behavior, add a keyword pair to set the default button. `tkMessageBox.askyesno('Yes or No?','Yes or No?', default='no')`

Comment: Of course, I can select a button with the mouse and focus on keyboard for  the dialog by Alt-Tabbing. However I want to select a button by cursor keys and press enter key just after appearing the dialog without any other operations for ease.  I will try bindings.

Comment: When I run this code on both windows and linux there are no problem with keyboard focus. 'Yes' has focus. (Pretty sure you can not solve this with bindings since tkMessageBox does not expose the actual buttons)

Comment: Certainly, the 'Yes' button was sometimes focused on my case. However the button was not focused in many cases, Editor in Spyder which I use as IDE was focused for keyboard. I don't know when the dialog gets focus.

Comment: I usually execute codes on IPython in Spyder. When I execute the above code on the command line, i.e. `!python C:/.../test.py` on IPython console, I can always make the dialog appear with keyboard focus. However, when I  execute the above code on  IPython console, I can NOT always make the dialog appear with keyboard focus. A keyboard focus on an editor in Spyder. Why are they different results? It seems to be a problem in Spyder. Is there any ways to always make the dialog appear with keyboard focus on  IPython console for ease (Running codes on the command line takes time little bit)?